# How to center divs horizontally?

Tags: css, html, alignment

Can someone help me with this? I've played with it a bunch and I can't figure it out, fixed it before but I forgot how to.

I'd like to align it horizontally without them overlapping vertically, would love the help. :)

Thanks, solved!

HTML:

```
     <div class="contain-info"><!-- contain -->
 <div class="info1">
 <h1>WHAT IS IT?</h1>
 <p>TEXT</p>
 </div>  

 <div class="info2">
 <h1>WHAT IS IT?</h1>
 <p>TEXT</p>
 </div> 

 <div class="info3">
 <h1>WHAT IS IT?</h1>
 <p>TEXT</p>
 </div> 
 </div><!-- contain -->
```

CSS:

```
.contain-info {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

 }

.info1 {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 }

.info1 p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info1 h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;

 }

.info2 {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;

 }

.info2 p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info2 h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;

 }

.info3 {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 float: right;
 }

.info3 p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info3 h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;
 }
```

Comment: Is there anything you want to achieve with `absolute` positioning?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this modified version [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9T8c/) I hope this is what your trying to achieve.

```
     .contain-info {
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     margin: auto;
     }
```

```
.info1 {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 }

.info1 p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info1 h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;

 }

.info2 {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 }

.info2 p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info2 h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;

 }

.info3 {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 }

.info3 p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info3 h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;
 }
```

I simply used

```
 margin:auto
```

on the

```
.contain-info
```

and removed off the inline-block styles

Comment: I'm trying to do this but horizontally across the page. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the **CSS flexbox model** — the possibility of using flexbox to achieve the layout you want is almost endless. It might be a little hard to begin with, but once you're familiar with the model it's quite easy to get things done the way you want.

```
.contain-info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In the example above, I ask the parent, `.contain-info` to display all children as flex items. The content is then justified, such that they will align themselves horizontally in the center of the parent element.

See proof-of-concept: <kbd>[JSfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2hf3u/)</kbd>

Mozilla has a [very comprehensive guide on using flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), but if you want a more user-friendly way to having it explained to you, look no further than [Chris Coyier's article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (currently down for site maintenance I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

Elements with center class will be in the middle of their parent element
Since you use divs. display:block is not necessary. Display of div's is block by default

```
.center
{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. I thought I always had to declare display:block

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <div class="contain-info"><!-- contain -->
 <div class="info">
 <h1>WHAT IS IT?</h1>
 <p>TEXT</p>
 </div>  

 <div class="info">
 <h1>WHAT IS IT?</h1>
 <p>TEXT</p>
 </div> 

 <div class="info">
 <h1>WHAT IS IT?</h1>
 <p>TEXT</p>
 </div> 
 </div><!-- contain -->
```

CSS

```
.contain-info {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

 }

.info {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 width:33%;
 }

.info p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;
 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Maw6u/

Answer (score 0):

you are using **display:inline-block** in contain-info. hence i will recommend you to use **text-align:center** in parent of contain-info.

And float is not a attribute used in absolute positioned elements you should use **left** and **right** attributes. 
Check out the solution - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/abFzf

```
.container {
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
.contain-info {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:100%;
 }

.info1 {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 left:0;
 position: absolute;
 }

.info1 p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info1 h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;

 }

.info2 {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 margin:0 auto;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 }

.info2 p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info2 h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;

 }

.info3 {
 font-family: "Bebas Neue";
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 right:0;
 }

.info3 p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: "Agency FB";
 }

.info3 h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-weight: normal;
 }
```

I hope it helps.